# Shall I use "an" before "impact"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Some uncountable words like the word **value** should not be preceded with article. I am not sure about **impact**.

> It has impact on the existing approaches.

or

> It has **an** impact on the existing approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "an" because "impact" is a noun and is singular.

With a verb, you don't need and should not use "an":

> It affects the existing approaches.

and with a plural noun, you should not use "an" but you may want some other word:

> It has impacts on the existing approaches.

Is grammatical but, to me at least, it reads a little oddly and you might want to put "some" or "many" or "a few" between "has" and "impacts".

Comment: Thanks. But I do not see my sentence which does not contain verb and not plural. So do you mean my sentence should be: "It has an impact on existing approaches"?

Comment: @None Yes, he means it. But you omitted **the** in front of **existing**, though I don't think that omission make any difference.

Comment: @None Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking.